# How can I enabled the initial data fetch use one endpoint, and future fetches use a different one?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a component that displays data in 2 tables and an API with the following endpoints `getAllTables`, `getTable1` and `getTable2`.

`getAllTables`:

```json
{
  table1: [...],
  table2: [...],
}
```

`getTable1`:

```json
{
  table1: [...]
}
```

`getTable2`:

```json
{
  table2: [...]
}
```

I call the `getAllTables` API endpoint to fetch all data for both tables on the initial load.
I then have buttons to trigger a refresh for each table, `Refresh table1` & `Refresh table2` which calls API endpoints `getTable1` & `getTable2`, respectively.

My intention is for the tables to be loaded initially using the endpoint `getAllTables` and then `Refresh table1` should invalidate the cache to automatically trigger a refresh using `getTable1` & `Refresh table2` should invalidate the cache to automatically trigger a refresh using `getTable2`.

I know that is doesn't automatically trigger the refresh because that data is only subscribed to the `getAllTables` endpoint.

Am I able to achieve my desired functionality? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up `useEffect` with an empty dependency that fetch all tables on initial load, while the refresh button subscribe to both get table 1 and 2.

Here's some dummy code, you can combine RTK with it:

```
const [table1, setTable1] = useState([]);
const [table2, setTable2] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const data = getAllTables(); // url point to get all

  setTable1(data.table1);
  setTable2(data.table2);
},[])

function refreshData() {
  cosnt table1Data = getTable1(); // url point to get table1 data
  cosnt table2Data = getTable2(); // url point to get table2 data

  setTable1(table1Data);
  setTable2(table2Data);
}

return (
  <button onClick={refreshData}>refresh</button>
);
```

The invalidation process is to simply override the previous data.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Although this may work, it doesn't fully utilize the benefits of RTK-Query's ability to auto-refetch data based on `invalidateTags` from mutations - explicitly calling `getTable1`/`getTable2` defeats it's purpose.